# Late at night with inverted colors on, dynamic background is inverted as well, how to stop it?

Tags: display, applescript, automator

I'm having the Catalina background in dynamic setting. I feel it really helps me to have a background that shows night and day on my laptop. However, now that I'm experimenting with working late at night, I'm noticing that the background is pretty white in both its dark mode and night mode.

How can I stop this from happening, can I script the background to not invert colors?

I suppose one hack I could do is to simply generate a script that inverts colors and chooses a white background that inverts to black. But I still wonder if one can invert their mac, but not their background image on their monitor.

Comment: Some food for thought... I just tested with a copy of my desktop background picture where in GIMP I inverted the colors of the image, saved it and set it as my desktop background picture. I then in System Preferences > Accessibility > Display checked the Invert colors checkbox.  It worked as expected. The process of switching the desktop background and changing the necessary settings can be scripted.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how they make the dynamic backgrounds in the first place. Maybe I can invert that?

Comment: Ah, they are called .heic files and they weren't located in where the Mac advice websites said they would be. So I ran `sudo find / -name "*.heic"` to check where they are. They're located in `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`

Comment: So I can copy them to `/Library/Desktop Picture` and it turns out that they're 8 images (I'm not sure which file format yet). So inverting them the other way around is easy. But it also makes it scriptable, since I noticed another issue that is related to this. So I'm going to see if I can make some script.